# jQuery-ui-dialog - Dropdowns dont stay open

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog

Using the dialog and adding different form elements.

My dropdowns will not stay open when you click the arrow button on the dialog.  You can HOLD down the button, but the click just shows the options and then it disappears.

Anyone seen this?

http://jsfiddle.net/tvance929/7pvb6/  -- This is an example of what I doing in a small measure... however, unfortunately this isn't displaying the issue I am experiencing.  I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that I am ajax'ing in info to the dropdowns and or adding extra styling...

Comment: don't by any chance have a jsfiddle example do you?